# How to get 3d representation of a deep learning model?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

Is there any way to get a picture (.png or .jpeg) depicting 3d representation of a deep learning network?

- For now, the model plotting utility of Keras gives a two-dimensional
  representation, comprising the number of layers and basic properties
  of each layer (reference image attached)
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGmiF.jpg
- Is there any way out in keras or any other library which can give me
  a 3-dimensional representation of the model for better visualisation?
  (reference image attached) https://i.stack.imgur.com/s027O.png
  [taken from Aligning Superhuman AI with Human Behavior: Chess as a Model System]
- If there isn't any library which can convert the model to a 3d representation/graph, Can anyone tell the software to create such graphics/ illustrations?

[image: 2d dimensional model from model plotting utility of keras]

[image: 3d model representation taken up from a research paper.]

Comment: https://github.com/HarisIqbal88/PlotNeuralNet

Comment: @lejlot Does it work for visualizing LSTMs and RNNs? I didn't find any documentation or examples for it.

Comment: This is just a library, it won't magically convert code to plots. You can plot something that will look like an RNN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try one of this:

1. Netron viewer for neural network: https://github.com/lutzroeder/Netron
2. Tensorspace ([introducing to tensorspace](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/tensorspace-js-a-way-to-3d-visualize-neural-networks-in-browsers-2c0afd7648a8/)): https://tensorspace.org/

Comment: This doesn't work for visualisation of LSTM network.

Comment: Second website is too rigid, it can't be used to save the visualisation. And the first website is more like keras's functionality to save model graph.